# Colour scale inversion with new version of ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a quality process where I need to export the exact same graphs over time. I mainly use the stacked bar chart from ggplot2 which is highly sufficient for me. Recently, I updated my ggplot2 version to ggplot2 2.2.0 and I cannot find a way to reproduce my previous graphs.

Here is my code :

```
DF1=data.frame(Rank=rep(1:4,3),variable=rep(c("F1","F2","F3"),each=4),value=c(500,400,300,200,250,100,155,90,50,30,100,10))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF1, aes(x = Rank, y = value, fill = variable)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

In the previous version of ggplot2, this code generated a graph where F1 was in pink, F2 was in green and F3 in blue. This is still the case but now the pink part is at the top of the bar (see image below)

[image: Difference between the two graphs]

I tried to reverse order of the variable factor, but now F1 is in blue etc which is not what I want neither.

```
DF1$variable=factor(DF1$variable,levels=rev(levels(DF1$variable)))
ggplot(DF1, aes(x = Rank, y = value, fill = variable)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Do you have any idea how I can find my good old graph back ? (going back to the previous version is not a viable version in a long term perspective)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set `reverse = TRUE` in `position_stack` to reverse the default stacking order (see `?position_stack`).

```
ggplot(DF1, aes(x = Rank, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE))
```

Which gives:

[image]